# Why do entertainment system headphones on aircraft have two pins?

Tags: airline-operations, passenger, inflight-entertainment

In most commercial flights where headphones are provided for inflight entertainment they have two pins, unlike single pin connections which we use on the ground (e.g. for mobile phones).
Is there a particular reason why it is done that way?

One reason could be that people can steal a single pin headphone. But still it is not compelling enough reason.

Comment: One reason - there are probably others - is that most airlines used to charge money for headsets (I think some still do on domestic flights) and they wanted to make sure that passengers couldn't just bring their own, so they created a deliberately incompatible connection to 'force' people to pay. But the last headphones I bought came with an airline adapter and some newer aircraft have regular single-pin connectors so I guess this is changing.

Comment: All of the aircraft that I've been on lately that had headphone plugs had just a normal single-prong 3.5mm jack on the IFE systems in economy, though I think the ones that provided noise-cancelling headsets in business class used special connectors (since they need to provide power to those headsets.)

Comment: @reirab Yes, the extra pin for noise cancelling power is quite normal in my experience

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The three main reasons are:

- Prevent theft of headphones due to incompatibility with home systems
- Redundancy, if one connector breaks, the other will still provide audio
- Before the 3.5mm jack was used, a pneumatic system was in use, which required two connectors.

This question has been asked on different websites already, but here is a detailed explanation that sums it up nicely:

> There are a couple main reasons:
>
> First, the airlines were trying to prevent theft of headphones. The two-pronged plugs have been around on airplanes since way before the airlines started charging for headsets. Back then, headphones were not usually easily carried around as the portable earbud style had not become popular yet. By using a two-pronged setup that is not used in most other audio systems, the motivation for passengers to steal the headsets went down immensely.
>
> The second reason is redundancy. When a standard stereo headphone jack with three internal connections (right, left, and ground) breaks, you will often lose audio in both the left and right channels. However, with the two-pronged design, if one of the jacks breaks then there will still be audio going through the other channel. While this is annoying for the user, it is an easy way for the airline to defer maintenance on that individual seat's audio system until both the left and right channel are non-functional.
>
> The two-prong design is a relic of the past, before headphones were bundled with so many of the mobile devices we now buy. Planes with updated inflight entertainment (IFE) systems usually have the standard stereo jack as most passengers prefer using their own headsets now. Slowly these old connectors will be completely phased out.
>
> Another less obvious (and probably less likely, but interesting nonetheless) reason, though, is based on airline complacency. Airlines, especially US based airlines, are notoriously slow in changing their tactics. Back before the 3.5mm jack became the standard for headphone audio connections for IFEs, airplanes used a pneumatic headphone design. These headphones were similar to stethoscopes where hollow tubes would be plugged into the armrest which had actual soundwaves coming out (instead of analog electrical signals). These systems were much more reliable than the standard electrical system and the headsets themselves were very cheap to replace. Since the pneumatic system required two separate plugs for the left and right channel (since you cannot mix physical sound waves into a single hole), all armrests were designed with two holes for audio. Airlines were likely so used to having two jacks for audio that they continued with the same design when they switched to electrical audio signals.
>
> <sup>(Source: [www.quora.com](http://www.quora.com/Why-do-airplanes-use-two-pronged-headphones) - Author: Raj Misra)</sup>

Comment: Glad you covered the old "sound tube" style - I remember those, and the offers from the flight crew to take them with you when you left. That always garnered confused looks from the pax, as they were useless for anything but the aircraft.

Comment: @FreeMan Credit where credit's due - I only quoted from the original author I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Aye, but you could have left that part out and no one would have noticed... ;) BTW - is your link the reference to the quote?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, I edited it now to make it more clear.

Comment: Talking about Quora on StackExchange is a ... taboo.

Comment: Sound-tube systems go back a *long* time.  At an antique phonograph and music box show, I saw a phonograph which was attached to about a dozen headsets, so an attendant in a hotel lobby could allow waiting guests to listen to music for a fee; this was before the days of electronic amplification, so the headsets were all pneumatic.

Comment: Current design include twin plugs compatible with single ones too...

Comment: @supercat Sound tubes are still around too: The headset I wear every time I fly uses sound tubes (granted they're connected to an individual speaker for each ear, and go to a standard electric plug, but they're still sound tubes).

Comment: @voretaq7 What's the reason you use sound tubes & not just electrically driven magnets?

Comment: @curious_cat That's just the way [the headset is designed](http://www.quiettechnologies.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=12). Seems to make more sense than constantly flexing the wires for the earpiece though.

Comment: @Farhan Why is it taboo, and where can the policy be found?

Comment: This is still currently the case on Qantas A380 I just feels between LAX and SYD. They provide a fragile adapter on the complimentary headphones that provides a single jack, but once I broke all of those I found I could put my headphones in either of the two jacks just right and get stereo output just fine